# Javascript WYSIWYG editor that works in a chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, wysiwyg

Are there any WYSIWYG editors that work in a chrome packaged app. Most of them don't seem to work with the increased security policy. Chrome complains about TinyMCE using unload. I have also tried nicedit, cleditor, wymeditor and a few others(can't quite remember).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own. The documentation on this page makes it easy. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Text Editor >>>>>> http://jqueryte.com/